# std::bind a member function to an object pointer

Tags: c++11, functional-programming

I have class with member functions:

```
typedef std::function<bool (const std::string &)> InsertFunction;    

bool insertSourceFile( const std::string & );
bool insertSourceDir( const std::string & );
bool insertHeaderFile( const std::string & );
bool insertHeaderDir( const std::string & );
```

I'd like to have a reference to one of these `InsertFunction`s in another class, and use it to do its job (without having to make classes for each of these functions). I tried using the class constructor and `std::bind` to bind the member function's implicit first argument to a pointer of the object in question:

```
new ListParser( p_target->sourceDirs(), bind(&Target::insertSourceFile, p_target, _1), this );
```

with

```
ListParser::ListParser( const stringSet &dirs, const InsertFunction &insert,
                        State* parent = 0 )
:   ParserState( parent ),
    m_dirs( dirs ),
    m_insert( insert )
{    }
```

**UPDATE**: thanks to @lijie, the source now compiles, but when the function m_insert is called, a `std::exception`is thrown for `std::bad_function_call`. What could be wrong? Thanks! If you need more info, please ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `insertSourceFile` is a *method* that returns a `std::function<etc>`. In your bind call, you are doing `Target::insertSourceFile()` which is invoking the method. Hence, the error.

**EDIT**
Specifically, Target::insertSourceFile is not a function that takes a string and returns a boolean.

I think what you are looking for is in `Target`, you declare
`bool insertSourceFile(const std::string &);`, etc. and then you do
`std::bind(&Target::insertSourceFile, p_target, _1)` but that is a guess until the intention is clarified.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with corrected syntax. I indeed want to use m_insert as a function taking a `const std::string &` and returning a `bool`, and that function being the one in `p_target` (hence the bind).

Comment: Never mind, I stored a const reference to the function object created as  temporary by `bind`, which resulted in an empty function object in some weird way. It now works and calls the right function! Thanks again!